# Unable to mount external harddrive (Openmediavault)

Tags: usb, hard-drive, mount

I try to connect a harddrive via a SATA to USB3 adapter to my raspberry (The adapter is externally powered, so there cannot be a power problem).

The adapter gets detected and shows up under `/dev/sda` but there is no `/dev/sda1` (There is one partition on the drive).

Following you see some commands and their output:

---

Before connecting:

```
root@raspberrypi:~# lsusb
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:9512 Standard Microsystems Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:ec00 Standard Microsystems Corp.
```

Afer connecting:

```
root@raspberrypi:~# lsusb
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:9512 Standard Microsystems Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:ec00 Standard Microsystems Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 174c:55aa ASMedia Technology Inc.
```

---

New log messages after connecting:

```
root@raspberrypi:~# tail -f /var/log/messages
Jun  9 22:48:24 raspberrypi kernel: [ 1551.505821] usb 1-1.3: new high-speed USB device number 9 using dwc_otg
Jun  9 22:48:25 raspberrypi kernel: [ 1552.447820] usb 1-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=174c, idProduct=55aa
Jun  9 22:48:25 raspberrypi kernel: [ 1552.447858] usb 1-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
Jun  9 22:48:25 raspberrypi kernel: [ 1552.447881] usb 1-1.3: Product: ASMT1051
Jun  9 22:48:25 raspberrypi kernel: [ 1552.447898] usb 1-1.3: Manufacturer: asmedia
Jun  9 22:48:25 raspberrypi kernel: [ 1552.447915] usb 1-1.3: SerialNumber: 123456789012
Jun  9 22:48:25 raspberrypi kernel: [ 1552.459682] usb-storage 1-1.3:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
Jun  9 22:48:25 raspberrypi kernel: [ 1552.460159] usb-storage 1-1.3:1.0: Quirks match for vid 174c pid 55aa: 400000
Jun  9 22:48:25 raspberrypi kernel: [ 1552.462992] scsi host5: usb-storage 1-1.3:1.0
Jun  9 22:48:26 raspberrypi kernel: [ 1553.457014] scsi 5:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ASMT     2105             0    PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
Jun  9 22:48:26 raspberrypi kernel: [ 1553.461797] sd 5:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI removable disk
Jun  9 22:48:26 raspberrypi kernel: [ 1553.462393] sd 5:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
```

---

With the adapter connected:

```
root@raspberrypi:~# ls -l /dev/sd*
brw-rw---T 1 root floppy 8, 0 Jun  9 22:48 /dev/sda

root@raspberrypi:~# parted /dev/sda
Error: Error opening /dev/sda: No medium found                            
Retry/Cancel?
```

---

The same adapter connected to my pc:

```
:~> sudo parted /dev/sdb print
Model: ASMT 2105 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 320GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End    Size   Type     File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  320GB  320GB  primary  ntfs         boot, type=07
```

---

I have Openmediavault(based on debian) installed.

What could be wrong? What can I do to get maybe more information or even get it running?

### EDIT:

I want to add, that the HDD is not even spinning.

### EDIT 2:

As requested in one of the comments here are the kernel versions of the Raspberry Pi and my PC.

Raspberrypi:

```
root@raspberrypi:~# uname -a
Linux raspberrypi 4.1.19+ #858 Tue Mar 15 15:52:03 GMT 2016 armv6l GNU/Linux
```

My PC:

```
:~> uname -a
Linux linux-l5eu 4.1.21-14-default #1 SMP PREEMPT Sun Apr 17 07:27:45 UTC 2016 (fc187c1) x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

So both shouldn't be too old, right?

And I have the Raspberry Pi model B(compare [here](http://elinux.org/RPi_HardwareHistory#Board_Revision_History)):

```
root@raspberrypi:~# cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep "Revision"
Revision        : 0002
```

Comment: Does the drive work when connected to a PC?

Comment: Can you also please share the type of adapter being used?

Comment: @MohammadAli I posted already the output of the adapter connected to my pc.

Comment: Have you tried using a 2.5 amp or greater power supply connected to your Pi?

Comment: @MohammadAli as I mention before the adapter is self-powered so this should not be a problem related to the power supply.

Comment: I know that you mentioned that the drive is self powered, but a lot of adapters only self power the drives but still rely on USB power for driving the adapter, so can you please try using a 2.5 amp or greater USB power supply to power the pi and tell me if it changed anything, also which Pi model are you using?

Comment: @MohammadAli I don't have a 2.5 amp power supply. I tried it with an 2.0 amp power supply, still the same result. Fo the model information see my edit above.

Comment: Do you have ntfs-3g package to recognize NTFS partition?

Comment: @Huczu Yes I do (At least the tool ntfs-3g is installed). And as far as I know it shouldn't really matter at device level. The partition table is 'msdos' so '/dev/sdX1' should show up anyway.

Comment: @exilit Can you please try setting `max_usb_current=1` in your `/boot/config.txt`, if you don't know how then just google it, also does your Pi work fine with other USB drives plugged into the same USB port your attempting to use for your hard drive?

Comment: @MohammadAli No luck either :(. Btw. Isn't this option available for Model B+ only? And yes, other usb devices work fine (except another USB3 external drive, but I'm quite sure that's a power issue).

Comment: @exilit yes you are right, see my answer for details on what I believe your problem is and how you can solve it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you state that your Pi is the original model b and that another external hard drive also does not work I believe that you are experiencing a power  issue. The original model b raspberry Pi used polyfuses to protect USB devices, but what this also did was limit the USB output current to approximately  140miliamps which should be enough for things such as USB drives, but with spinning media your Pi won't be able to provide enough power to the drive as you have noticed with the other non externally powered drive that you own. Although you are under the impression that your adapter bring externally powered that this can not be a power issue. I believe that your adapter simply believes that it isn't connected when it is, this is likely because your adapter is expecting the USB slandered minimum current of 500ma.

To solve this I belive that you should purchase a powered USB hub, or to bridge the polyfuses on your Pi to increase the power output limit. You can find out how to do this [here](http://theiopage.blogspot.ca/2012/06/increasing-raspberry-pis-usb-host.html?m=1)

Comment: I can confirm anecdotally that I have not gotten a USB drive to power directly from a model B, or read anyone else here claiming they have; the + and later models are fine (although except for the 3, you must add `max_usb_power=1` to `/boot/config.txt`).

Comment: Thanks for your great answer first. I should concern doing this change, but first I want to get more information related to the polyfuses on the internet. And although I realy like your answer I am little bit sceptical because the log shows that it is detected and connected. But maybe I should just give it a try.

Comment: @exilit you could always try a powered hub, I believe that it may be because a lot of drive adapters use things like NPN transistors to start the drive up, now although being externally powered, still require the base of the transistor to be powered to the USB specification of .5 amps which the Pi is not capable of. This is done to prevent the drive from running all the time to increase its life span, and it may still be connected in the log because often with drive adapters, the USB chip in them will be always running to allow for the fastest possible drive access times.

Comment: @MohammadAli I remember that I had problems with a powered hub before, but not sure right now... One more question to that solution: Do you know any drawbacks or risks using this approach?

Comment: @exilit which approach?, the powered hub or bridging the polyfuse?

Comment: @MohammadAli bridging the poly fuses.  After reading that newer models use this approach too I think this should be safe?

Comment: @exilit yes it should be relatively safe, the polyfuses main purpose was to originally stop people from connecting high powered USB devices to the Pi and have it reboot at random, but that shouldn't be a problem for you if you use a decent power supply, please mark this answer as correct if it has helped you

Comment: @MohammadAli I will test this tomorrow an then report. I am quite sure you will earn the bounty.

Comment: You are my personal hero. It works now, even without the external power supply. Sadly I have no oscilloscope to check the voltage, so I think I will connect the power supply anyway. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @exilit not a problem, you will probably want to keep the external power plugged in, I've seen some adapters that just include fake power supply's to get people to buy them or it may only draw power from the wall when doing large sequential reads or writes when the drive needs to up the rpm from idle is often when that external power supply will come in handy

Answer (score 0):

You are using a SATA-to-USB3 adapter. Raspberry Pi does not support USB3. :)

Comment: But USB 3 is backward compatible,  isn't it?

Comment: It is, but this a USB3 adapter, not a USB3 device. USB3 devices have their data paths setup so that they can still work with USB2 ports, your adapter may have it's data paths setup for max performance, making it USB3-only. Try it on a USB2 port on your laptop.

Comment: @thingan Trying it on a USB2 port seems to work also.

Comment: which kernel are you running on the Pi? On your desktop?

Comment: @JayEye I edited my question. It now contains information about the kernel versions.

Comment: @MohammadAli bridging the poly fuses.  After reading that newer models use this approach too I think this should be safe?

Answer (score 0):

I would try it in another way. First I would take a look at fdisk

root@Raspi:~# **fdisk -l**

this shows something like this

```
[...]
Device         Boot  Start      End   Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/mmcblk0p1        8192   137215    129024   63M  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
/dev/mmcblk0p2      137216  31116287 30979072 14,8G 83 Linux

Disk /dev/sda: 931,5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x965a1a59

Device     Boot Start        End     Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1            63 1953520064  1953520002 931,5G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
```

(I noticed that it depends on witch of the 4 USB Connectors you plug your Hard-drive, you get different values for your  removable devices sda1 sdb1 ... etc ..)

and then you prolly want to do this:

```
root@Raspi:~# mount -t vfat -o utf8,uid=pi,gid=pi,noatime /dev/sdb1 /media/usbstick
```

But you could go a step forward and ask your box:

```
root@Raspi:~# ls -al /dev/disk/by-uuid/
insgesamt 0
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 100 Jun 13 15:38 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 120 Jun 13 05:46 ..
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 Jun 13 15:38 1105-1008 -> ../../sda1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  15 Jun 13 05:46 202638e1-4ce4-45df-9a00-ad725c2537bb -> ../../mmcblk0p2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  15 Jun 13 05:46 22E0-C711 -> ../../mmcblk0p1
```

The UUID in this case is 1105-1008

now knowing the UUID you could mount it by UUID

```
root@Raspi:~# udisksctl mount --block-device /dev/disk/by-uuid/1105-1008
```

have fun.

Comment: Thank you, I will give it a try before doing any hardware modifications. But to be honest I do not expect much of it as it seems not to be inserted into the device tree.